# Simple data visualization from data to create/place circles/spere on grid

Tags: c++, image, visualization

all I want is to create circles (from data) on a grid for specific sets of data with different colours. These might be objects I have created to be placed on grid or from the program itself. I was using POVRAY but it is massively complicated and I don't have the time. Unless anyone has a tutorial on how to read data from files and extract all the numbers and used successfully in .pov files.

Comment: Is there something specific that requires this to be C++ ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered [GNUplot](http://www.gnuplot.info/)?

It has a simple syntax, so you can just convert your data file into an input file for gnuplot.

Answer (score 0):

There are several programs/environments (not C++) that can do this directly. One is [gnuplot](http://www.gnuplot.info/); another, more robust tool is [R](http://www.r-project.org/). Although with R there is a bit more of a learning curve to really get moving.